# How to send form data to REST api in ionic 3

Tags: arrays, laravel, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

when I send data to REST API it sending in a single array like

```
Array ([  
   {  
      "username":"karthik@w3cert_in",
      "password":"05550",
      "grant_type":"password",
      "client_id":"Outfit1548925669",
      "client_secret":"a10620c85033ab02b582d17716cda245"
   }
]=> )
```

but i need to send a data like this

```
Array
(
    [username] => karthik@w3cert.in
    [password] => 05550
    [grant_type] => password
    [client_id] => Outfit1548925669
    [client_secret] => a10620c85033ab02b582d17716cda245
)
```

this is the code which i'm using:

```
 let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl  + 'oauth/access_token';
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers});


  let postcredentials = {
      'username' : credentials.username,
      'password' : credentials.password,
      'grant_type' : credentials.grant_type,
      'client_id' : credentials.client_id,
      'client_secret' : credentials.client_secret,
  };

    console.log('iii'+(postcredentials) );
       this.http.post(apiUrl, postcredentials,  options)
         .subscribe(res => {
           console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
         }, (err) => {
           console.log(apiUrl);
         });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of store data into object make array like this.

```
 let   postcredentials = [];
   for (var prop in credentials) {
        postcredentials[prop]= credentials.prop
   }
```

Comment: can you please explain what is prop that you have mentioned @pal

Comment: prop is key of the object @Karthik

Comment: if we use like this it shows as error on prop...

 let   postcredentials = [];
  for (var prop in credentials) {
       postcredentials[username]: credentials[username],
  }

Comment: please check edited answer it should be "=" not ":"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190548/discussion-between-pal-and-karthik).

Comment: error on this line > postcredentials[username] = credentials[username],

username shows as error

Comment: use this credentials.prop

Comment: Please put a console.log of credentials

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Laravel parses your request and collects all request parameters (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) into a single array, which is what you see here:

```
Array ([  
   {  
      "username":"karthik@w3cert_in",
      "password":"05550",
      "grant_type":"password",
      "client_id":"Outfit1548925669",
      "client_secret":"a10620c85033ab02b582d17716cda245"
   }
]=> )
```

Also, every request parameter is a key-value pair combination, therefore, each request value must have a key that is used to access it, and that means you will have to assign a key to the data group below to access it as a single array.

```
let postcredentials = {
      'username' : credentials.username,
      'password' : credentials.password,
      'grant_type' : credentials.grant_type,
      'client_id' : credentials.client_id,
      'client_secret' : credentials.client_secret,
};
```

Something like this:

```
let postcredentials = {
      'auth_data': {
          'username' : credentials.username,
          'password' : credentials.password,
          'grant_type' : credentials.grant_type,
          'client_id' : credentials.client_id,
          'client_secret' : credentials.client_secret,
       }
 };
```

Then in your Laravel controller, you can get the data like so:

```
public function loginFn(Request $request){
    print_r($request->auth_data);
}
```

To see:

```
Array
(
    [username] => karthik@w3cert.in
    [password] => 05550
    [grant_type] => password
    [client_id] => Outfit1548925669
    [client_secret] => a10620c85033ab02b582d17716cda245
)
```

Hope this helps.